# Why is fontspec not working with the new Overleaf version update?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

I am writing a paper that requires specific fonts on Overleaf. I imported the ttf files with the fonts I need and placed them in a a folder named fonts within another folder called style. I then created font familes for them using the following code.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\gplay[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{EBGaramond-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\gplaybf[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{EBGaramond-Bold.ttf}
\newfontfamily\play[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{Play-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\playbf[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{Play-Bold.ttf}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

And this worked exactly how I wanted it to. However, when I upgraded my overleaf version I now see the following error.

```
                 % avoid possibly uncorrected "system" fonts
The package fontspec has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [no-math]
Adding the global options:
  ,no-math
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: newtxtext loads fontspec too, but with different options. Either use \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}, or do not load fontspec and move your font definitions behind newtxtext.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that worked thank you. Do you know why this was not an issue with the previous Overleaf Version?

Comment: the newtx package changed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%fonts
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\gplay[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{EBGaramond-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\gplaybf[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{EBGaramond-Bold.ttf}
\newfontfamily\play[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{Play-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\playbf[Path=./Style/Fonts/]{Play-Bold.ttf}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```